# WinForms ComboBox DropDown and Autocomplete window both appear

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, autocomplete

I've got a `ComboBox` on a winforms app with this code:

```
comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;

DataTable t = new DataTable();
t.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
t.Columns.Add("Display", typeof(string));

for (int i = 1; i < 2000; i++)
{
    t.Rows.Add(i, i.ToString("N0"));
}

comboBox1.DataSource = t;
comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Display";
```

I then follow these steps when the window opens:

1. Click the `ComboBox` drop down button -- this displays the list of items and selects the text in the `ComboBox`
2. Type '5', '1' ... i.e. I'm looking to use autocomplete to search for 515, 516, etc.
3. You'll see that the autocomplete window now appears ON TOP of the drop down list.  However if I mouse over, it's the obscured drop down window behind the autocomplete window that's receiving the mouse events, including the click.  So I think I'm clicking on an autocomplete item but actually clicking on something totally random that I can't see.

Is this a bug in the `ComboBox`?  I'm using Windows 7 if that matters.  Am I configuring the `ComboBox`wrong somehow?

Note also that using the KEYBOARD uses the autocomplete drop down.  So up/down arrow keys are using the front window, but the mouse is using the back window.

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with that - they're just trying to give you the best of both worlds!!

Comment: There is an easy and effective work around. But since SO tells me not to answer questions in the comments, I won't. But I did answer it below...as an answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No problem getting a repro for this simply by setting the properties from the PropertyGrid.  Behaves this way both in Win7 and Windows XP.

This is broken behavior documented in this [feedback article](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/254605/combobox-autocomplete-mouse).  As indicated, Microsoft is not considering a fix.  One possible workaround is to disable autocomplete in a DropDown event handler and re-enable it in a DropDownClosed event handler.

Comment: I hate to see folks come to SO looking for an answer, taking a look at the accepted answer for that question -- which doesn't really solve their problem -- then leave without an answer. Before you become one of these people, look at the answer to this question with my name...it really does solve this problem easily and completely.

Comment: Check out @JoeGayetty 's answer.

Comment: if microsoft not considering a fix . what does peopl use instead of that buggy datagridview??

Answer (score 31):

Add a single line of code to your `ComboBox` `KeyDown` event and the problem is solved!

```
private void comboBox_NameAndID_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    comboBox_NameAndID.DroppedDown = false;
}
```

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/32dddabe-7c66-4c67-b24b-bab8b6ab25cc/combobox-dropdown-and-autocomplete-window-both-appear-in-winform?forum=winforms)

Comment: Your comment under the accepted answer grabbed my attention. Thanks for that. It really solves it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and comments, it's resolving an issue I've been bumping into for a long time...

Answer (score 2):

I'm a Brasilian student of encoding and I lose many hours seeking to fix it im my project. And here, I saw it in a few seconds!!!

My code seems like this:

```
private void populateCombos()
    {
        persist.ShowLst(dspMember, vlMember,varTable,lstBox,varWhere);
        persist.ShowLst(dspMember, vlMember,varTable,ddlist1,varWhere);
        persist.ShowLst(dspMember, vlMember,varTable, ddlist2,varWhere);

        ddList1.Text = null;
        ddList2.Text = null;

        lstBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        lstBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
        lstBox.Text = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to the/a keypress event.

```
    Dim box As ComboBox = sender
    box.DroppedDown = False
```

Answer (score 1):

Select the ComboBox from the design view and set "Append" to the AutoCompleteMode property, this will suggest the item without apearing a window.

Answer (score 0):

That's weired. Your code looks fine to me and I used this the AutoComplete feature a several times and it didn't show both the DropDown and the AutoComplete list.

My suggestion would be

- Set the DataSource after the Display/Value Members. I can't remember why but the other caused some problems.

  ```
  comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
  comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Display";
  comboBox1.DataSource = t;
  ```
- Set the AutoCompleteSource at the end of your code (after adding the DataSouce)

Maybe that helps.

Comment: Those changes didn't make a difference.  Were you able to duplicate the problem?  If not, what OS are you using?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

to only have one open at a time you can use comboBox1.Droppeddown = true open up the regular, false the AutoComplete will only appear

Answer (score 0):

You simply add item in collection.

Now go properties option of combo box choose 
AutoCompleteSource=ListItems
AutocompleteMode=suggest

note: autocomplete source have many option as per your requirement :)

Answer (score 0):

WinForms ComboBox DropDown...the answer is this...
write below code in comboBox1 Enter event..

```
private void comboBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
}
```

Now for comboBox1 AutoComplete...
write this `AutoComplete()` in page load event..so it work...

```
public void AutoComplete()
{
    try
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new 
        MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=databasename;user
            id=root;password=;charset=utf8;");
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select distinct
            (columnName) from tablename", conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds, "tablename");
        AutoCompleteStringCollection col = new
        AutoCompleteStringCollection();

        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            col.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["columnName"].ToString());
        }
        comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        comboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col;
        comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
    MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the ComboBox from the design view and set "None" to the AutoCompleteMode property.

Answer (score 0):

Many years later, I encountered this same issue. While the actual answer (@JoeGayetty) works, it wasn't enough for me.

To preserve the desired suggestion behavior, I used an AutoCompleteMode of **SuggestAppend** and most importantly a DropDownStyle of **DropDownList** (which is not the default). Doing this corrected the duplicate drop-down problem for me while preserving the desired suggestion behavior:

```csharp
myComboBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
myComboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

As a secondary data point, the original problem seems to only (I think) happen when the content of the combobox is wider than the control.