# How can I reduce the DropDownHeight of a ComboBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, autocomplete, combobox

I've implemented autocompletition by extending WinForm comboboxes. What I want to do now is to reduce the dropdown height when typing.

I've tried stuff like:

```
this.DropDownHeight = this.ItemHeight * this.Items.Count
```

at the end of the `KeyUp` event handler, but the result is very weird.

How can I solve this little problem?

Comment: What is the criteria for height reduction ?

Comment: It was to reduce the height to the numbers of items shown

Comment: Cody has given a great insight on that .. voted for the same

Answer (score 6):

The `DropDownHeight` property controls the height of the combo box when it is dropped-down.

*(Yes, you say, that much is obvious!)*

But that is **not** the same thing as the list of auto-complete suggestions.

*(What? They look the same; they're both dropped down lists of items!)*

Yes, they are. But they're implemented quite differently behind the scenes. A drop-down combo box is the same as a "full" combo box (the style is called "Simple" in WinForms) where the drop-down portion is permanently displayed on the screen. The only difference is that with the "DropDown" or "DropDownList" styles, the drop-down portion is hidden and displayed only when requested by the user. ([A comparison of various combo box styles](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC510541.png).) The original intention of this style was to save screen space, but now it's become so popular that everyone uses it instead, even though screen space is no longer a concern.

What that means is that the drop-down item list *does not change*. Windows does not re-use the same drop-down list to display the auto-complete suggestions. That's an entirely different pop-up window being created and destroyed as needed. The dead give-away of this is that the auto-complete suggestion list is *resizable*. It has one of them there resize grippers in the corner. The regular drop-down list does not have this, so they clearly can't be one in the same. Technically, the auto-complete suggestion list is implemented by the shell [`IAutoCompleteInterface`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776292.aspx), and is the same one used by all edit controls. (Another dead give-away is found in bugs like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064780/winforms-combobox-dropdown-and-autocomplete-window-both-appear).)

So you *actually* need to change the drop-down height of the auto-complete suggestion list! But unfortunately, WinForms does not expose any property for doing so.

Thus it's reasonable to conclude that you probably **shouldn't be doing this** in the first place. Allow the user to resize the auto-complete suggestion box as they choose. That's what the resize gripper is there for. The last size that they selected is remembered and re-used. Always respect the user, even when your design department thinks that they can do something "better".

But of course, since this is Windows, there's a way to fix your problem if you're willing to get your hands dirty. The auto-complete suggestion list is still a window, so it still has a window handle, and Windows will let you manipulate virtually any window that you can get a handle for. I don't necessarily suggest doing this, so I'll leave you [on your own](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/csdoesshell4.aspx) to hack up a solution. Keep in mind that when functionality like this is unexposed, it's typically unexposed for a reason. Your hack is likely to break on future versions of Windows, where the shell team re-tools the auto-complete functionality. Hardly worth the support hassle.