# How can I find out if a combo box contains a value member?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

The situation is that I have 2 controls, a text box and a combo box. The user can select something in the combo box, it fills the text box with the value member, if the user types into the text box, I want to check if it exists in the combo box's values and then select the corresponding display member.

The method I was expecting to be there was something like

```
if(cmb1.valueMembers.Contains(txt1.Text))
```

but I can't find anything like this, I also thought looping through them could find it? so I've got

```
foreach (System.Data.DataRowView row in cmb1.Items)
        {}
```

but can't find the value member anywhere in the row?

Thanks

Comment: Just a suggestion: why don't you use the AutoComplete property of the combobox and get rid of the textbox? - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletemode.aspx

Comment: Also, check out this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064780/winforms-combobox-dropdown-and-autocomplete-window-both-appear

Comment: I'm not using the auto complete because the value member is what I need to be entered into the text box, the display member is what I'm showing in the combo box

Comment: @Dimitar I've edited my question because I wasn't too clear on that, thanks though

Comment: How do you bind the values to the combobox ? maybe you can try by assigning the `SelectedValue` property of the ComboBox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, here's a simple example but I guess that's the main idea. We have a `MyClass` which have `Id` for the ValueMember and `Name` for the DisplayMember.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass(string name, int id)
        {
            Name = name;
            Id = id;
        }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    List<MyClass> dsList = new List<MyClass>();

    public Form1()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            dsList.Add(new MyClass("Name" + i , i));
        }

        InitializeComponent();

        comboBox1.DataSource = dsList;
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Checks if item with the typed Id exists in the DataSource
        // and selects it if it's true
        int typedId = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        bool exist = dsList.Exists(obj => obj.Id == typedId);
        if (exist) comboBox1.SelectedValue = typedId;

    }


    private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyClass obj = comboBox1.SelectedValue as MyClass;
        if (obj != null) textBox1.Text = obj.Id.ToString();
    }
}
```

Feel free to ask if something's not clear.

**PS: In the example I'm assuming that integers will be typed in the textbox**

Comment: Oh okay, so basically I should keep a list of the display members and the values so that I can just look at the list to find the relationship? My application works a little different but yes that's perfect and I can go from here, many thanks!

Comment: You always need to provide datasource for the control. One property from the objects in the datasource is used for the DisplayMember and another one for the ValueMember

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the game but I couldn't find anything useful so I came up with this simple solution:

```
comboBox1.Items.OfType<SomeType>().Any(x => x == YourValue)
```

Or:

```
comboBox1.Items.OfType<SomeType>().Any(x => x.SomeProperty == YourValue)
```

---

### Example to demonstrate:

```
class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// ...

var people = new List<Person>() { /* Add some data */ };
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
comboBox1.DataSource = people;

// ...

bool exists = comboBox1.Items.OfType<Person>().Any(p => p.Id == 1);
```

Or if you need to get the index of the item, you can use something like this:

```
var person = comboBox1.Items.OfType<Person>().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == 1);
var index = (person != null) ? comboBox1.Items.IndexOf(person) : -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ListSubCategoryProduct = await Task.Run<List<SubCategoryProduct>>(() => { 
    return productsController.ListSubCategoryProduct(CategoryProductId); }); // <- I search the database

                CboSubCategory.DataSource = ListSubCategoryProduct;
                CboSubCategory.DisplayMember = "Description";
                CboSubCategory.ValueMember = "SubCategoryProductId";

                CboSubCategory.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
                CboSubCategory.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;

                this.CboSubCategory.SelectedValue = 1; // <- SubCategoryProductId. You have to know the ID.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        bool _found = false;
        string _txt = comboBox1.Text;
        foreach (var row in comboBox1.Items)
        {
            if (_txt == row.ToString()) { _found = true; }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedValueChanged
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then              
        Return
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString   ' if find then show their displaymember in combobox.
    End If


Private Sub TextBox1_Leave(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Leave
    Dim value As String = TextBox1.Text
    ComboBox1.SelectedValue = value                                    ' if find then show their displaymember in combobox.

    If ComboBox1.SelectedValue Is Nothing Then                          ' if the id you entered in textbox is not find.
        TextBox1.Text = String.Empty

    End If
```