# How to check text of combobox with database column's value

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, combobox

I am new to programming, it may be a simple task, but I am facing difficulties.

I have a combobox in a Windows forms that is linked with a table column named `id` in SQL Server. I want to check that the value entered in the combobox exists in the column. If yes, then further working and if not, then error message to user and it should work whether user press Enter, Tab or Selection changed .

code for  Filling the combobox

```
         sqlCmd.Connection = con;
         sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT pid FROM report2";
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new
           System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
        sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
        comboBox1.DataSource = dtRecord;
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "pid";
        con.Close();
```

*** id is alphanumeric.

Thanks in advance

so far  i have done this , but i am getting error message for all multiple timed even their is matched value in item list...

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= comboBox1.Items.Count-1; i++)

        {

            if (comboBox1.Text.Equals(comboBox1.GetItemText(comboBox1.Items[i]).ToString()))

            {
                con.Open();
                string sql = "SELECT * FROM report2 where partno='" + comboBox1.Text + "'";
                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                dataadapter.Fill(ds, "report2");
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
                dataGridView1.DataMember = "report2";
                dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;

                con.Close();
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("enter valid value for for loop");
            }
```

Comment: Please post the code which you have tried so far.

Comment: Please show us some code. How you are preserving the column values? Is it list/array/dictionary ?

Comment: @mukul , i have updated my question . hope now you will understand it . if any query let me know . thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

This might be asolution for you.

First, get combobox value, which was selected just recently.

Then, assuming that you are using EF, check against database with combobox selected id.

And lastly, either show message and do nothing if there is no such id, or continue with your logic if the is such id in table

```
private void yourCombobox_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
    int selectedComboboxId = yourCombobox.SelectedValue;

    bool recordExists = _context.Set<YourEntity>().Any(x=>x.Id = selectedComboboxId);

    if(recordExists){
        //record is in the table
        //your code
    }
    else 
    {
        //record is not in the table
        MessageBox.Show("Record does not exist. Select new option.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Entity Framework (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723(v=vs.113).aspx). `_context` is a `DbSet`, but this line can be replaces with `SqlCommand `

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `combo`box as `dropdownlist`. This will restrict user from entering any new value to the `combobox` so you don't require to show error message to user.

Try below,

```
sqlCmd.Connection = con;
sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT pid FROM report2";
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);                                                                                                                                                                                                               
DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList; //this statement added
comboBox1.DataSource = dtRecord;
comboBox1.ValueMember = "pid";
con.Close();
```

Comment: thanks but list is too long , so this will not work ,

Comment: Did you looked into the link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064780/winforms-combobox-dropdown-and-autocomplete-window-both-appear